# The skin color of bonobos

Tags: evolution, zoology, skin

Why is that bonobos skin color on the areas not covered by hair are dark throughout life unlike the chimpanzee?

Comment: "*disprove the idea that skin color evolved*".. How is this related to evolution?

Comment: I removed it. If it wasn't related then excuse me.

Comment: Most likely they're different because ... they're different. Chimps and bonobos are separate species, and have evolved many different traits from each other over time. The difference in skin color may have evolved as an evolutionary advantage of some sort (maybe bonobos spend more time in direct sunlight than chimps), or it may just be an artifact, or side effect of some other mutation.